# Setting up Fortran in Eclipse PTP via homebrew

Tags: eclipse, macos, fortran, homebrew, gfortran

Using homebrew on my El Capitan(10.11.6), i installed java and eclipse-ptp through the following commands:

```
brew cask install java
brew cask install eclipse-ptp
```

I have gcc and thus gfortran through homebrew from earlier.

Eclipse PTP got copied into the Apps successfully. I opened the application and created a helloworld demo project and tried to build it. I get the following message in the build console window:

```
make all 
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
gfortran -O2 -g \
        -o bin/demo \
        src/demo.f90
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I glean that this issue maybe due to improper setting of the path variable, what i do fail to understand is:

1. Given that all the installs happened through homebrew, why is this problem appearing?
2. How do i fix this issue?